# Does I wrong using Batch Script with CMD?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, echo

When I type:

```
set hi=Hello World
echo %hi%
echo hi is "%hi%"
```

and run I should see "Hello World" , "hi is "Hello World"" Right ?

But I got this message "" , hi is ""

What? what happen to me.

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

I'm a newbie to Bat scripting please help me.

Update this is my all

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r %%G in ("T00   ?.mp3") do (
set hi=Hello World
echo %hi% <------ this I got echo is off
echo hi is "%hi%"
pause
)
```

It already get in loop.

Comment: You indeed should get what you expect, but the code you've shown us will not produce what you've reported. It's very important to cut-and-paste your exact code - don't retype it. I suspect you actually have `set hi = Hello World/echo "%hi%"/echo hi is "%hi%"`

Comment: [link](http://superuser.com/questions/725918/how-to-rename-file-using-cmd-track-mp3-to-t00-mp3) is what I wanna do but I think all of my variable is emty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard problem.

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

```dos
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r %%G in ("T00   ?.mp3") do (
set hi=Hello World
echo !hi!
echo hi is "%hi%" at the start of the loop, but !hi! if it is changed in the loop
pause
)
```

Note that when you use `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` to turn *delayed expansion* ON, %var% accesses the value when the *block* was **parsed** and !var! the **run-time** value.

Since `hi` was not defined when the loop started, the command seen was `ECHO`, so `cmd` reported the `echo status` (`echo is OFF`) (which you didn't tell us originally.)

If you use ECHO<kbd>(</kbd>%hi% then you'll find that id `hi` is empty, `ECHO` will show nothing (ie. just produce an empty line)

And also shows the importance of posting the exact code you are using...